# The unbearable opaqueness of time.struct_time

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pycharm, pylint

Why do pylint and the intellisense features of IDEs have trouble recognizing instances of `time.struct_time`? The following code contains some trivial tests of existent/non-existent attributes of classes, named tuples and the named-tuple-like `time.struct_time`. Everything works as expected in pylint, IntelliJ and VSCode - the access to missing attributes is reported in each case except for `time.struct_time` - it generates no warnings or errors in any of these tools. Why can't they tell what it is and what its attributes are?

```
import time
from collections import namedtuple

t = time.localtime()
e = t.tm_mday
e = t.bad # this is not reported by linters or IDEs. 

class Clz:
    cvar = 'whee'

    def __init__(self):
        self.ivar = 'whaa'

o = Clz()
e = Clz.cvar
e = o.ivar
e = Clz.bad
e = o.bad

Ntup = namedtuple('Ntup', 'thing')
n = Ntup(thing=3)
e = n.thing
e = n.bad
```

The context of the question is the following recent bug in `pipenv` -

```
# Halloween easter-egg.          
if ((now.tm_mon == 10) and (now.tm_day == 30))
```

Obviously, the pass path was never tested but it seems the typical static analysis tools would not have helped here either. This is odd for a type from the standard library.

(Fix can be seen in full at https://github.com/kennethreitz/pipenv/commit/033b969d094ba2d80f8ae217c8c604bc40160b03)

Comment: Probably because `time.struct_time` is in C, so they can't inspect its source for valid attributes.

Comment: Sure, it probably has something to do with it but I don't think it's quite enough. These tools don't get confused by every C-implemented type. They're perfectly happy with lists, etc.

Comment: They need specific handling for lists that isn't in place for `time.struct_time`.

Comment: Again, that sounds plausible but is entirely speculative. Why wouldn't it be in place? Would't much of this stuff be autogenerated? What else is missing, then? etc.

Comment: If you try to go to the function definition it mentions `def localtime(seconds=None): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__`. So if real signature is not known then how would lint work?

Comment: @TarunLalwani that is a stub generated by IntelliJ itself, so while it says something, it's a bit circular - intellij gets this wrong because intellij gets this wrong. Additionally, in intellij's case, you can see a similar stub for say, `len` which intellij seems to know returns an int, even though it's not in the stub.

Comment: @pvg: It's a C structure and not statically introspectable. Many autocomplete systems generate stub files to get around this, but they are often incomplete and out of date. In future, the [type hinting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) will help as the community will [maintain stub files](https://github.com/python/typeshed/) for the standard library at least. Flake8 with the mypy plugin does detect this issue because [stub file defines the object](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/time.pyi).

Answer (score 3):

`time.struct_time` is an object defined in C, which means it can't be introspected statically. The autocompletion software can parse Python code and make a reasonable guess as to what classes and namedtuples support, but they can't do this for C-defined objects.

The work-around most systems use is to generate stub files; usually by introspecting the object at runtime (importing the module and recording the attributes found). For example, CodeIntel (part of the Komodo IDE), uses an [XML file format called CIX](https://community.activestate.com/faq/codeintel-cix-schema). However, this is a little more error-prone so such systems then *err on the side of caution*, and will not explicitly mark unknown attributes as wrong.

If you are coding in Python 3, you could look into using [type hinting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). For C extensions you still need stub files, but the community is pretty good at maintaining these now. The standard library stub files are maintained in a [project called *typeshed*](https://github.com/python/typeshed/).

You'd have to add type hints to your project:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from collections import namedtuple


t: time.struct_time = time.localtime()
e: int = t.tm_mday
e = t.bad  # this is not reported by linters or IDEs.


class Clz:
    cvar: str = 'whee'
    ivar: str

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.ivar = 'whaa'


o = Clz()
s = Clz.cvar
s = o.ivar
s = Clz.bad
s = o.bad

Ntup = namedtuple('Ntup', 'thing')
n = Ntup(thing=3)
e = n.thing
e = n.bad
```

but then the [flake8 tool](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) combined with the [flake8-mypy plugin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8-mypy) will detect the bad attributes:

```
$ flake8 test.py
test.py:8:5: T484 "struct_time" has no attribute "bad"
test.py:22:5: T484 "Clz" has no attribute "bad"
test.py:23:5: T484 "Clz" has no attribute "bad"
test.py:28:5: T484 "Ntup" has no attribute "bad"
```

PyCharm builds on this work too, and perhaps can detect the same invalid use. It certainly [directly supports pyi files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html).

Comment: I think this is actually inaccurate in the case of pylint, as (somewhat inadvertently) suggested by one of the commenters. Pylint doesn't get these not because of the C'ness of the struct but because it just doesn't (and can't easily) know much about return types to begin with. It fails on the returns of `len`, `split`, etc. It does know what objects from builtins look like, but it doesn't know something (that it didn't parse itself) gives you one.  typeshed claims to be used by IntelliJ yet that flunks `struct_time` but it's a good pointer for a bit of further digging.

Comment: @pvg: `pylint` doesn't have the stub files.

Comment: I get that, but pylint would get this wrong whether the return was a C struct or not. It doesn't get far enough to be stumped by the thing being defined in C. And, of course, it can introspect builtins at runtime which I imagine it does (or at least, pre-flgihts). But again, that doesn't help it. On the other front, I did have a chance to take a quick look at typeshed and that contains accurate stubs for these particular calls and the struct, so that's an upvoteworthy direction of inquiry.

Comment: No, pylint doesn't check return types; it isn't sophisticated enough for that. Flake8, without the mypy plugin, wouldn't either.